# Can I set dynamic column widths in GridManagerLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a `recyclerView` with a `gridManagerLayout` like this:

```
GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(Main.this, 10);
manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

Is there a way to set different widths to each column? I am trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

As you can see columns 0, 2, 4, 6 and 8 need to be smaller than the others.

I have tried `manager.setSpanSizeLookup(spanSizeLookup)`, but I don't want to change the `spanCount` of the `layout manager`.

This is what I have right now[image]

I am setting the width of each holder in the constructor by calling
    itemView.getLayoutParams().width = THE_WIDTH;

It looks like the yellow lines are in their place, don't know why the others have an offset

This is the XML for the image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/text"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Category name"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#7f007f"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the xml for the space between them

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="25dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffff00"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, set the Width of the item dynamically using layout.params,eg.

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
10,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Check,

```
if(position%2==0) {
your_item_parent_layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
10,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
else{
your_item_parent_layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
100,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

in your adapter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: upload your both xml files too

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use `getItemViewType` method of your `Adapter` and in that you have to send type of your layout and in `onCreateViewHolder` you need to  `inflate` your `layouts` according to your type. And You can set `width` and `height` to your two different `layouts` as shown in the screenshot

Comment: I am already doing that in the constructor of each holder, according to its type.

Comment: @kimv then where is the problem? It should work well